# why wso2 API manager doesn't show all scopes in recourse section(only list 25)?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I defined 50 scopes and when I want to assign it to resource's scope I only see 25 of them.is this a bug and how can I handle it ?(showed in below picture)
[image]

Comment: What's the version of APIM?

Comment: Available issue - https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9660

Comment: Should be fixed in 4.x versions